# How to zoom cube

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Hello I want to make a div with text and when I click on this it should rotate, zoom to blank page and display new content. How can I do it? It's what I already have.

**JavaScript:**

```
var props = 'transform WebkitTransform MozTransform OTransform msTransform'.split(' '),
    prop,
    el = document.createElement('div');

for(var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(typeof el.style[props[i]] !== "undefined") {
        prop = props[i];
        break;
    }
}

var xAngle = 0, yAngle = 0;
$('#cube').on('click',function(){
  yAngle = -180;
  document.getElementById('cube').style[prop] = "rotateX("+xAngle+"deg) rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)";

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqxmC/)

Comment: What's the issue? I click it, and it rotates to a new page... How do you mean "zoom to blank page and display new content"...